# The confidence interval of $\tau^2$ and $I^2$ produced by the meta and metafor packages

Tags: meta-analysis

I am comparing R packages including `metafor` and `meta` for meta-analysis. Both packages are excellent and most of the results are the same. However, I found that the confidence intervals of $\tau^2$ and $I^2$ provided by `metafor` are different from those of the `meta` package (and also other meta-analysis software such as MedCalc). Am I missing any parameter in the `metafor` package? Or how can I fix the inconsistency?

```
> library(metafor) # Load metafor package
> CCDES1=escalc(measure="ZCOR", ri=c(0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.45), ni=c(40, 90, 25, 400, 60, 50)) # Calculating individual effect size
> AGGCCD=rma(yi=yi, vi=vi, data = CCDES1, method="DL") # Aggregating effect sizes
> confint(AGGCCD) # Get confidence interval for indices of heterogeneity

       estimate   ci.lb   ci.ub
tau^2    0.0819  0.0114  0.3023
tau      0.2861  0.1067  0.5498
I^2(%)  86.1663 46.4352 95.8332
H^2      7.2287  1.8669 23.9990

> library(meta) # Load meta package

> m1=metacor(cor=c(0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.45), n=c(40, 90, 25, 400, 60, 50), sm="ZCOR", method.tau="DL",backtransf = TRUE) # Aggregating effect sizes
> m1
   COR           95%-CI %W(fixed) %W(random)
1 0.50 [0.2233; 0.7021]      5.72      15.47
2 0.60 [0.4487; 0.7179]     13.45      18.05
3 0.40 [0.0058; 0.6866]      3.40      13.23
4 0.20 [0.1040; 0.2923]     61.36      19.97
5 0.70 [0.5425; 0.8100]      8.81      16.95
6 0.45 [0.1962; 0.6473]      7.26      16.33

Number of studies combined: k=6

                        COR           95%-CI      z  p-value
Fixed effect model   0.3584 [0.2895; 0.4236] 9.5396 < 0.0001
Random effects model 0.4875 [0.2714; 0.6568] 4.1045 < 0.0001

Quantifying heterogeneity: tau^2 = 0.0819; H = 2.69 [1.89; 3.82]; I^2 = 86.2% [72%; 93.2%]

Test of heterogeneity:      Q d.f.  p-value
 36.14    5 < 0.0001

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Fisher's z transformation of correlations
```

Answer (score 6):

The `metafor` package computes the CI for $\tau^2$ using the Q-profile method, which is described in:

Viechtbauer, W. (2007). Confidence intervals for the amount of heterogeneity in meta-analysis. *Statistics in Medicine, 26*(1), 37-52.

This is an exact CI, so it is guaranteed to have nominal coverage (under the assumptions of the model).

Since $I^2$ and $H^2$ are just functions of $\tau^2$ (and the 'typical' sampling variance; for details, see [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/faq#how_are_i_2_and_h_2_computed_i)), one can just take the CI bounds for $\tau^2$, plug them into the equation for obtaining $I^2$ and $H^2$, and thereby obtain exact CIs for $I^2$ and $H^2$.

The `meta` package uses the method described in section A2 in:

Higgins, J. P. T., & Thompson, S. G. (2002). Quantifying heterogeneity in a meta-analysis. *Statistics in Medicine, 21*(11), 1539-1558.

This is an approximate CI that does not always have nominal coverage.

Comment: Dear Dr. Viechtbauer, Thanks a lot for your prompt answer.